# Magento 2: Disabled products are still visible in Frontend

Tags: magento2, category-listing, disabled-products

I have disabled the product from admin panel but still the product are visible in the frontend.

**Expectation:** Product should not visible in frontend when disabled it via admin.

**Actual Result:** Products are visible in frontend though disabled in admin

At initial, our website mode is in multi store mode, now we have changed it on single store mode. Also, we have some of the custom product attributes and store view was set to `Global`.

Is that because of store view of product attributes?

Please guide

Comment: did your indexer run and cache cleared? also check config if you have to display out of stock products

Comment: Did you reindex and clear cache after you disabled the products?

Comment: please check in storeview level that products were enable or not

Comment: if you have only one store then turn single store mode on your magento, it will help to increase speed

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, I have already changed the mode to single store mode. After changing the mode, in product page at admin, there is no dropdown to check storeview level. How can I check it?